# Matlab GUI - Display image selected in popupmenu to axes

Tags: matlab, popupmenu

I need to display the image in an axes which i selected in popup menu.
I am generating the popup menu list dynamically by using the following code:

function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

DirEntries = dir('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\Images');
uicontrol('Style','popup', 'String', {DirEntries.name});

Now which ever image that i select in this pop up menu should be displayed in 'axes'

Can anyone help me on how to display the selected image in the GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the job

```
function script
figure;
directory = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\Images';
Dir = dir(directory);

axes;
h = uicontrol('Style','popup', 'String', {Dir.name}, 'Callback', @popupmenu1_Callback);
setappdata(h,'Dir', directory);



function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
value = get(hObject, 'Value');
directory = getappdata(hObject, 'Dir');
images = get(hObject, 'String');
% Do a check if this is a valid image
imshow(strcat(directory,'/', images{value}));
```